# Projection of a convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ onto $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, linear-transformations, polyhedra

Suppose  $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector.

$$X=\{ x\in  \mathbb R^n: A x\leq b\}$$

Is it possible to compute the projection of $X$ on  $(x_1,x_2) $ manually and analytically? That is,

$$X_{1,2}=\{  (x_1,x_2)\in  \mathbb R^2:   x\in X\}$$

Thanks.

Comment: yes, is it just the slice in $R^n$.

Comment: Use quantifier elimination, like Fourier-Motzkin or Loos-Weispfenning. But doing this manually is no fun :(.